# How to create a product catalog without using the Product Catalog App

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list, catalog

I would like to know the best way to create a product catalog without using the product catalog app as I don't have access to this feature.  I'm using Sharepoint 2013, but this feature is deactivated and will not be activated anytime in the future.

I've created a custom list and put all my products in, with a title, description, image, price and metadata.

I now need the user to be able to sort the list by price or the metadata, but am now stuck!

I've played with the content search and refiners web parts and have also looked into the metadata tree navigation, but I'm not sure what is the best (and easiest!) way to achieve what I need.

Any pointers would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

The **Product Catalog** is a site template, not an app. This template comes with the **Cross-Site Collection Publishing** site collection feature pre-activated. From what I understand you do not even need this feature to be activated.

If you simply want to sort items in a list, then that can be easily achieved similar to Excel: click on the column name in the list view and you will be presented with two option for sorting - A to Z, and Z to A.

If you want refiners, the again clicking the column name should offer you a drop-down listing the values stored in that column for all items in the list view.

For refiners, you can also use Metadata Navigation available as hierarchy fields or as a input/search box on the left-hand side of the list view. To enable and configure this, go to the list settings and then to the **Metadata Navigation Settings**.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response - I want the data to look like a catalog, not just a list. I've enabled enterprise metadata and keywords on the list and populated the column with these I'm just struggling to put it all together.